# При запуске в Windows 7 дописывает к именам файлов программы .txt

Tags: c++builder

Здравствуйте! Есть программа, которая сначала разархивирует bz2 архив, а потом производит над ним нужные действия. Архир помещается в каталог folder_for_arhiv. Разархивируется и переименовывается на разрешение .txt. В Windows XP все работает хорошо, а Windows 7 после разархивирования переименовывает все файлы в папке, добовляя .txt, а в папку folder_for_arhiv не заходит и файл из архива не трогает. Кусок кода:

```
    int f;
    AnsiString Path = "folder_for_arhiv\\*.bz2";
    AnsiString zx;
    AnsiString zx2;

    TSearchRec sr;
    int done = FindFirst( Path, faAnyFile, sr );
    while(!done) {
          s->Add(sr.Name);

      done = FindNext(sr);
     }
     FindClose(sr);
            for(int i=0;i<s->Count;i++) {  //Проходимся циклом по всему списк

            zx = zx + "folder_for_arhiv\\" + s -> Strings[i] + " ";
            zx2 = zx2 + s -> Strings[i] + " ";
            }       
    zx = "bunzip2.exe " + zx;

    s -> Clear();

    zx2 = zx + "\ncd /folder_for_arhiv \nren *.* **.txt";

    f = FileCreate("C:\\sss.bat");

    FileWrite(f,zx2.c_str(),zx2.Length());
    FileClose(f);

    WinExec("C:\\sss.bat",SW_SHOW);
```

Проблема в том, что не воспринимает эту строку при выполнении BAT файла:

```
    zx2 = zx + "\ncd /folder_for_arhiv \nren *.* **.txt";
```

В ХР все нормально работает. После распаковки получается файл без расширения, при помощи этой строки в ХР преходит в каталог folder_for_arhiv и добовляет в конец файла .txt

Как переделать, чтобы работало в Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю дело в том что без супер пользователя нельзя выполнять программы с C: в win7.
Вариантов решения несколько:

1. исполняемый бат файл перенести куда нибудь в более адекватное место (темп, папка пользователя, локальные данные программы)
2. Выполнить программу с правами суперпользователя.

Comment: Программа запускается от имени Администратора.
Запуск на разархивировании и переименование файлов выполнятся нормально, а вот преход в директорию folder_for_arhiv не хочет, эта директория находися в том же каталоге где и EXE файл программы

Comment: ну я думаю имеет смысл в бате тогда прописать полный путь а не относительный

Comment: "соль" в том, что папка с программой может находится в любом месте...

Comment: получив полное имя файла программы, извлекаете оттуда путь и подставляете в бат.